# How to take depth of neural network as argument while constructing Network in Pytorch

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

I have written following code to take depth of network as parameter in Pytorch. 
Later I realized even if I am using many hidden layers, the learnable parameters remain the same.

```
class Net3(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_feature, n_hidden, n_output, depth, init):
        super(Net3, self).__init__()
        self.input = torch.nn.Linear(n_feature, n_hidden).float().to(device)   
        self.hidden = torch.nn.Linear(n_hidden, n_hidden).float().to(device)   
        self.predict = torch.nn.Linear(n_hidden, n_output).float().to(device)   =
        self.depth = depth 


    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.input(x))      # activation function for hidden layer
        for i in range(self.depth):
           x = F.relu(self.hidden(x))      # activation function for hidden layer
        x = self.predict(x)           
        return x
```

Is there any other way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

In init you need to create *multiple* hidden layers, currently you're only making one. One possibility to do this with little overhead is using a `torch.nn.ModuleDict` that will give you named layers:

```
class Net3(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_feature, n_hidden, n_output, depth, init):
        super(Net3, self).__init__()
        self.layers = nn.ModuleDict() # a collection that will hold your layers

        self.layers['input'] = torch.nn.Linear(n_feature, n_hidden).float().to(device)

        for i in range(1, depth):
            self.layers['hidden_'+str(i)] = torch.nn.Linear(n_hidden, n_hidden).float().to(device)  

        self.layers['output'] = torch.nn.Linear(n_hidden, n_output).float().to(device)   =
        self.depth = depth 


    def forward(self, x):
        for layer in self.layers:
            x = F.relu(self.layers[layer](x))

        return x
```

Comment: FYI: my implementation above also applies relu to the output layer, but you should be able to figure that out yourself.  You could either decide to apply the activations in the forward pass, as above, and making sure each layer has its correct activation. Another possibility is adding the activations to `self.layers` itself using `nn.ReLU()` instead of `F.relu`